# Need Header on Top for Horizontal UICollectionView UIKIT

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewflowlayout, uicollectionreusableview

I am implementing custom headers for UICollectionView

I need a header on the Top for Horizontal CollectionView.

[image]

Comment: You will need to create a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` to achieve this - if you find this tricky, I can prepare an example if you like ?

Comment: @ShawnFrank Yeah, please share the example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, creating a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` is one way to get the results you want. This is quite a complex topic so the explanation is quite long.

Before adding some code, you will need to understand the different components in a `UICollectionViewLayout` such as cells, supplementary views and decoration views. Check [this out to know more](https://ioscoachfrank.com/components-collection-view-layout.html)

In your example, above the headers are called `Supplementary views`which are of type `UICollectionReusableView` and the cells are, well, your cells of type `UICollectionViewCells`.

When assigning a layout to a collection view, the collection view makes a sequence of calls to its layout to understand how to lay the views out.

Here is an example of this I found of this:

[image: UICollectionView Custom Layout]

*source: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest*

In your custom layout, you must `override` these to create the layout you desire:

- prepare()
- collectionViewContentSize
- layoutAttributesForElements(in:)
- layoutAttributesForItem(at:)
- layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind:, at:)
- invalidateLayout()
- shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange)

Setting up the layout is a bit complex, mainly because of the math involved but at the end of the day, it is just about specifying frames (x, y, width, height) for the different cells and supplementary views at for different viewports.

**Custom Layout example**

First I created a very basic reusable view to be used as the header above the cells in each section and this just has a label in it

```
class HeaderView: UICollectionReusableView
{
    let title = UILabel()
    
    static let identifier = "CVHeader"
    
    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutInterface()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        layoutInterface()
    }

    func layoutInterface()
    {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        title.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        title.backgroundColor = .clear
        title.textAlignment = .left
        title.textColor = .black
        addSubview(title)
        
        addConstraints([
        
            title.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            title.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            title.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
            title.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor)
            
        ])
    }
}
```

Next I set up my collection view in a normal way, the only difference is I provided a custom layout class

```
// The collection view
private var collectionView: UICollectionView!

// A random data source
let colors: [UIColor] = [.systemBlue, .orange, .purple]

private func configureCollectionView()
{
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero,
                                      collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
    
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
    
    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self,
                            forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    
    // This is for the section titles 
    collectionView.register(HeaderView.self,
                            forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
                            withReuseIdentifier: HeaderView.identifier)
    
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self
    
    view.addSubview(collectionView)
    
    // Auto layout config to pin collection view to the edges of the view
    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    collectionView.leadingAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor,
                    constant: 0).isActive = true
    
    collectionView.topAnchor
        .constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor,
                    constant: 0).isActive = true
    collectionView.trailingAnchor
        
        .constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor,
                    constant: 0).isActive = true
    
    collectionView.heightAnchor
        .constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
}

private func createLayout() -> HorizontalLayout
{
    // Not flow layout, but our custom layout
    let customLayout = HorizontalLayout()
    customLayout.itemSpacing = 10
    customLayout.sectionSpacing = 20
    customLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
    
    return customLayout
}
```

Data source and delegate also has nothing too different but I am adding it for completeness

```
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        // random number
        return 3
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        // random number
        return 8 + section
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView
            .dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"cell",
                                 for: indexPath)
        
        cell.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.section]
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: 200, height: 50)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String,
                        at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
    {
        let header
            = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
                                                              withReuseIdentifier: HeaderView.identifier,
                                                              for: indexPath) as! HeaderView
        
        header.title.text = "Section \(indexPath.section)"
        
        return header
    }
}
```

Finally, the most complex part, creating a custom layout class. Start by looking and understanding the instance variables we keep track of, this will change based on the layout you want to create

```
class HorizontalLayout: UICollectionViewLayout
{
    // Cache layout attributes for the cells
    private var cellLayoutCache: [IndexPath: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = [:]
    
    // Cache layout attributes for the header
    private var headerLayoutCache: [Int: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] = [:]
    
    // Set a y offset so the items render a bit lower which
    // leaves room for the title at the top
    private var sectionTitleHeight = CGFloat(60)
    
    // The content height of the layout is static since we're configuring horizontal
    // layout. However, the content width needs to be calculated and returned later
    private var contentWidth = CGFloat.zero
    
    private var contentHeight: CGFloat
    {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return 0 }
        
        let insets = collectionView.contentInset
        
        return collectionView.bounds.height - (insets.left + insets.right)
    }
    
    // Based on the height of the collection view, the interItem spacing and
    // the item height, we can set
    private var maxItemsInRow = 0
    
    // Set the spacing between items & sections
    var itemSpacing: CGFloat = .zero
    var sectionSpacing: CGFloat = .zero
    
    var itemSize: CGSize = .zero
    
    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
```

We then need a function to help us figure out how many items can fit in 1 column based on the cell height, spacing and available space based on the collection view height. This will help us move the cell to the next column if there is no more space in the current column:

```
private func updateMaxItemsInColumn()
{
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
    
    let contentHeight = collectionView.bounds.height
    
    let totalInsets
        = collectionView.contentInset.top + collectionView.contentInset.bottom
    
    // The height we have left to render the cells in
    let availableHeight = contentHeight - sectionTitleHeight - totalInsets
    
    // Set the temp number of items in a column as we have not
    // accounted for item spacing
    var tempItemsInColumn = Int(availableHeight / itemSize.height)
    
    // Figure out max items allowed in a row based on spacing settings
    while tempItemsInColumn != 0
    {
        // There is 1 gap between 2 items, 2 gaps between 3 items etc
        let totalSpacing = CGFloat(tempItemsInColumn - 1) * itemSpacing
        
        let finalHeight
            = (CGFloat(tempItemsInColumn) * itemSize.height) + totalSpacing
        
        if availableHeight < finalHeight
        {
            tempItemsInColumn -= 1
            continue
        }
        
        break
    }
    
    maxItemsInRow = tempItemsInColumn
}
```

Next, we need a function to help us find the width of a section as we need to know how long the header view should be

```
private func widthOfSection(_ section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return .zero }
    
    let itemsInSection = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
    
    let columnsInSection = itemsInSection / maxItemsInRow
    
    // There is 1 gap between 2 items, 2 gaps between 3 items etc
    let totalSpacing = CGFloat(itemsInSection - 1) * itemSpacing
    
    let totalWidth = (CGFloat(columnsInSection) * itemSize.width) + totalSpacing
    
    return totalWidth
}
```

And as mentioned above, we need to override a few functions and properties. Let's start with `prepare()`

```
// This function gets called before the collection view starts the layout process
// load layout into the cache so it doesn't have to be recalculated each time
override func prepare()
{
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return }
    
    // Only calculate if the cache is empty
    guard cellLayoutCache.isEmpty else { return }
    
    updateMaxItemsInColumn()
    
    let sections = 0 ... collectionView.numberOfSections - 1
    
    // Track the x position of the items being drawn
    var itemX = CGFloat.zero
        
    // Loop through all the sections
    for section in sections
    {
        var itemY = sectionTitleHeight
        var row = 0
        
        let headerFrame = CGRect(x: itemX,
                                 y: 0,
                                 width: widthOfSection(section),
                                 height: sectionTitleHeight)
        
        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader,
                                                          with: IndexPath(item: 0, section: section))
        attributes.frame = headerFrame
        headerLayoutCache[section] = attributes
        
        let itemsInSection = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
        
        // Generate valid index paths for all items in the section
        let indexPaths = [Int](0 ... itemsInSection - 1).map
        {
            IndexPath(item: $0, section: section)
        }
        
        // Loop through all index paths and cache all the layout attributes
        // so it can be reused later
        for indexPath in indexPaths
        {
            let itemFrame = CGRect(x: itemX,
                               y: itemY,
                               width: itemSize.width,
                               height: itemSize.height)
            
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)
            attributes.frame = itemFrame
            cellLayoutCache[indexPath] = attributes
            
            contentWidth = max(contentWidth, itemFrame.maxX)
            
            // last item in the section, update the x position
            // to start the next section in a new column and also
            // update the content width to add the section spacing
            if indexPath.item == indexPaths.count - 1
            {
                itemX += itemSize.width + sectionSpacing
                contentWidth = max(contentWidth, itemFrame.maxX + sectionSpacing)
                continue
            }
            
            if row < maxItemsInRow - 1
            {
                row += 1
                itemY += itemSize.height + itemSpacing
            }
            else
            {
                row = 0
                itemY = sectionTitleHeight
                itemX += itemSize.width + itemSpacing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The content size property

```
// We need to set the content size. Since it is a horizontal
// collection view, the height will be fixed. The width should be
// the max X value of the last item in the collection view
override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize
{
    return CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
}
```

The three layout attribute functions

```
// This defines what gets shown in the rect (viewport) the user
// is currently viewing
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?
{
    // Get the attributes that fall in the current view port
    let itemAttributes = cellLayoutCache.values.filter { rect.intersects($0.frame) }
    let headerAttributes = headerLayoutCache.values.filter { rect.intersects($0.frame) }
    
    return itemAttributes + headerAttributes
}

override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
{
    return cellLayoutCache[indexPath]
}

override func layoutAttributesForSupplementaryView(ofKind elementKind: String,
                                                   at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes?
{
    return headerLayoutCache[indexPath.section]
}
```

And finally the invalidate layout

```
// In invalidateLayout(), the layout of the elements will be changing
// inside the collection view. Here the attribute cache can be reset
override func invalidateLayout()
{
    // Reset the attribute cache
    cellLayoutCache = [:]
    headerLayoutCache = [:]
    
    super.invalidateLayout()
}

// Invalidating the layout means the layout needs to be recalculated from scratch
// which might need to happen when the orientation changes so we only want to
// do this when it is necessary since it is expensive
override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool
{
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return false }

    return newBounds.height != collectionView.bounds.height
}
```

With all of this in place, this should give you this result:

[image: Custom UICollectionView layout swift iOS UICollectionViewLayout flow layout customization]

If for some reason you weren't able to add the code to the right sections, have a look at this same example with the [complete source code here](https://github.com/shawn-frank/StackOverflow/tree/production/CustomCollectionViewLayout)

While I cannot cover everything, here are 3 great tutorials you can look at after going through this answer to understand more in depth:

1. [Ray Weldenrich: UICollectionView Custom Layout Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/4829472-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest)
2. [Building a Custom UICollectionViewLayout from Scratch](https://ioscoachfrank.com/layout-from-scratch.html)
3. [Custom Collection View Layouts](https://www.objc.io/issues/3-views/collection-view-layouts/)

Comment: thanks a lot Shawn! One of the things that i didn't get why there is need to cache the layout, isn't UICollectionView itself uses cached cell attributes for previously shown items and just changes the contents?

Comment: @yosoybunal - The UICollectionViewCell is what get's cached automatically when you use UICollectionViews. That is the view itself, not the layout which is things like the size and coordinates. If you notice the custom layout class, we do some heavy calculations to calculate the layout and the UICollectionViewCell lifecycle might request layout information several times and so we do not want to recalculate the layout each time and this is the reason we cache the layout information. I recommend going through https://ioscoachfrank.com/layout-from-scratch.html which might explain things better.